# OnclickListener Not Working properly For Dynamically Inflatted View

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-inflate

I am facing a problem on dynamically created Layout on a fragment. Here is my Fragment code

```
public class Points extends Fragment {
LinearLayout gameListHolder;
String name;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_game,null);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    gameListHolder=view.findViewById(R.id.gameListHolder);
    for(int i=0;i<=3;i++){
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View addView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.game_list_single, null);
        name=Integer.toString(i);
        Button status= (Button) addView.findViewById(R.id.statusButton);
        status.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.i("Rahat",name);
            }
        });
        gameListHolder.addView(addView);
    }
}
```

}

My Problem is, when I click on the status button it always gives me the value of last index in my case 3. I want it to be when i clilck the first button it will give me the value of first index, then for second it will give me value of 2nd index.

Comment: It's because the variable `name` is a member variable and is mutable. The last value set to it was `3` and so when you click the button, it shows 3. This is not a good way to create lists. Consider using recyclerview and adapter instead

Comment: I suggest you to use listview instead of this dynamically adding items

Comment: When i log the values before that onclick its showing perfect value. The problem is happening only on the onclick block

Answer (score 0):

Please using local "name" variable as below :

```
String name=Integer.toString(i);
```

Comment: it will not be known to the onclick block

Answer (score 0):

You have the option to set tag to your button and then in onclick you can check the 
     tag to find which button is clicked. i.e

```
    item.setTag(name);
    status.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Log.i("Rahat",view.getTag().toString());
                }
            });
```